# What is the best way to setup the updating process when there is one field inside each item is contently updated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

What I'm looking to do is create a Cooking Alarm app.

I'm using the MVVM architecture and would like to update it via LiveData.

This is the alarm class I have.
every second, all of the `item`s inside the `data` will be touched and the `tick` should be called. `tick` will update the `timeLeft`, which should be reflected onto the UI. However, the other components of the screen should stay the Same.

The only thing that's regularly updated is the text that would represent the time left(which I've yet to write the code to convert from int to string).
What the best way to make sure that the recycler view only updates the time and doesn't waste their time to set up the image and item name all over again?

```
class Alarm(item: Item, private val context: Context, val notifyID: Int) {

    var timeLeft = item.timeInSec
    val name = item.name
    val imageUri = item.imageUri

    var isFinished = false

    // count down goes down every seconds
    fun tick() {
        timeLeft--
        if (timeLeft <= 0) {
            onFinish()
        }
    }

    fun onFinish() {
        isFinished = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Use diffutil to update efficiently the items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using LiveData, RecyclerView, and ViewModel.

Activity:

```
    private MyVM mVM;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(...);
        mVM = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyVM.class);
        mAdapter = new Adapter(mVM.getStuff().getValue(), getLayoutInflater());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mVM.getStuff().observe(this, stuff -> {
            mAdapter.setItems(stuff);
        });
    }

    static class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.VH> {

        private // list items ;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        Adapter(..., LayoutInflater i) {
            ...
            mInflater = i;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new VH(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position) {
            //set views in holder
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            //return size of the collection
        }

        public void setItems(...) {
            // update with diffutil
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        static class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            // views

            VH(View v){
                super(v);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyVM extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<...> stuff;

    public MyVM(){
        // initialize and mutate stuff
    }

    public LiveData<...> getStuff(){
        return getStuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the UI updating code should be inside my Fragment, which gets triggered by subscription to my ViewModel?

Comment: Alright thanks, Ill try that approach and see if it breaks

Comment: One more question, should I have two copy of the data? One in the Adapter while the other one in the viewModel? or should they just refer to the same thing?